# Parse large number of xml files in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'll be getting a large number of xml files (numbering in tens of thousands every few minutes) from an MQ. The xml files aren't very big. I have to extract the information and save it into a database. I cannot use third party libraries unfortunately (except the apache commons). What strategies/techniques are normally used in this scenario? Is there any xml parser in java or apache which can handle such situations well?

I might also add that I'm using jdk 1.4

Comment: STAX is built-in and works well.  [Linkage.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/using.html)

Comment: should it be atomic operation ? I mean what should if there is some error in some xml ?

Comment: wow that was quick :) Thanks, I'll have a look. However, how do i handle those database inserts?

Comment: @Sach: If there is an error, i just have to log it and proceed with the next xml

Comment: Use a database `INSERT`.  [Moar links.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) However when you say "MQ" you may be in an environment (JEE) where there's an already defined source or API for databases.  Ask for requirements.

Comment: @markspace I meant that is it ok to hit the database tens of thousands of times in a few minutes? I should've mentioned that tens of thousands xmls every few minutes

Comment: Should be, yes.  You do have to try (test) your app eventually, so if it's not OK you'll have to deal with it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and discussion around this topic - I would like to propose a consolidated solution.

1. Parsing XML files using SAX - As @markspace mentioned, you should go
   with SAX which is built-in and has good performance.
2. Use BULK INSERTS if possible - Since you plan to insert a large
   amount of data consider what **type** of data are you reading and
   storing into the database. Do all the XML files contain the same
   schema (which means they correspond to a single table in the
   database) OR do they represent different objects (which means you
   would end up inserting data into multiple tables).

   In case the schema of all XML files that needs to be inserted into
   the same table in the database, then consider batching these data
   objects and bulk-inserting them into the database. This will be
   definitely more performing in terms of time as well as resources
   (you would open only a single connection to persist a batch as
   opposed to multiple connections for each objects). Of course you
   would need to spend some time in tuning your batch size and also
   deciding the error handling strategy for batch inserts (**discard
   all** v/s **discard erroneous**)

   If the schema of the XML files are different, then consider clubbing
   similar XMLs into groups so that you can BULK INSERT these groups
   later.
3. Finally - and this is important : Ensure that you release all the
   resources such as File handles, Database connections etc once you
   are done with processing or in case you encounter errors. In simple
   words use `try-catch-finally` at the correct places.

While by no means complete, hope this answer provides you a set of critical checkpoints that you need to consider while writing scalable performant code

Comment: Thanks Prahalad. Another question would be how do we decide the frequency of these bulk inserts?

Comment: @lemonTea There is no definite answer to this question. You would have to decide the frequency of the bulk inserts depending upon various factors such as memory consumption,constraints on the time limit within which the data must be persisted to the database and so on. The only way you can determine the right parameters is by observing application performance for a range of values in an environment that simulates production